# Literature recommendation how statistics is used to make age/size/population/... estimates in biology

Tags: estimation, references, biostatistics

I was always interested how statistics is used to estimate e.g.

- Weight of an animal from its foot size
- Age of a shark from some measurements in its eyes
- Age of a tree
- Approximate population of some species

Is there any book/article/tutorial/course/ where can I read more about some examples how these estimates are made?

Comment: Some generic approaches include *ratio estimators* and *regression estimators,* among others.  See Thompson's *Sampling* or Cochran's *Sampling Techniques* for classic textbooks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relationships between two measurements of size of an organism are very simple: they are usually just based on a linear regression between the two quantities. Look up [allometric scaling relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allometry) for more on this topic. For example, [here's a paper](https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1741-7007-10-60) linking bone length and body mass. It finds very strong relationships:

[image: Femur length vs. body mass]

Once a relationship like this is established, the regression can be used to make predictions for any other species when you have measurements of just one of the two quantities. This is seen most often in the case of extinct species, for which we estimate mass based on fossil bones.

Relationships based on age are a little more complicated because they are not linear, but the principle is the same. The [von Bertalanffy growth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Bertalanffy_function#:%7E:text=The%20von%20Bertalanffy%20growth%20function,length%20from%20age%20in%20animals.) is often used for this, though it has been criticised and extended. [This paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.192146) is relevant.

Population size estimation is a larger and more complex topic. [Mark-recapture methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) are one way that population sizes are estimated by ecologists.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the most ancient observed growth (decline) regularity is Seneca's Effect, "It would be some consolation for the feebleness of our selves and our works if all things should perish as slowly as they come into being; but as it is, increases are of sluggish growth, but the way to ruin is rapid." Lucius Anneaus Seneca, Letters to Lucilius, n. 91 which follows an inverted s-shape and linearizes if visualized as a log-log graph.
[image]

See Ugo Bardi's book *The Seneca Effect* https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Seneca_Effect/F14yDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Gibbon popularized Seneca's Effect with his famous *The History of the Decline and Fall of the Roman Empire* beginning in 1776. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_the_Decline_and_Fall_of_the_Roman_Empire

The earliest known nonlinear (s-shaped) parametric power law was developed by Benjamin Gompertz in 1825. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function

[image]

Efforts before Gompertz were either linear (de Moivre) or quadratic (nonparametric polynomials) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_growth

The logistic growth curve is owed to Verhulst in 1838 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

It's of interest to note that Gompertz and logistic functions differ in the length or duration of the growth stage, Gompertz' being significantly slower. It's regrettable that statistical software developers have settled on the ubiquitous use of the logistic growth curve without exploring or offering alternatives such as Gompertz'.
[image]

Later, Rubner (1883) and Kleiber (1932) derived metabolic scaling laws relating mass (by species) and metabolism. https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.01540
[image]

Von Bertalanffny's growth model came much later in 1959. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5756614/

These models tie together in papers such as *Biological and statistical interpretation of size-at-age, mixed-effects models of growth*  https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.192146

And books such as *Statistical Methods for Trend Detection and Analysis in the Environmental Sciences* or *Age-Period-Cohort Analysis: New Models, Methods, and Empirical Applications* https://www.google.com/books/edition/Statistical_Methods_for_Trend_Detection/zLh3OkKWJ7QC?hl=en&gbpv=0  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Age_Period_Cohort_Analysis/9udMBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

A good overview of all of this is Banks, *Growth and Diffusion Phenomena* https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-03052-3

Of course, these citations are just the tip of the iceberg wrt growth curves. Many more have been proposed, typically as they apply to disciplines other than biology.

*Logistic substitution model and technological forecasting* using the Fisher-Pry transform https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705811001469  Note, however, that the F-P transform is deterministic, ie, it lacks an error term.

Derek J. de Solla Price's book  *Little Science, Big Science* he applies sigmoid growth curves to scientific citations and publications. Price's Law is a mathematical principle that states that a small number of individuals in any organization or group are responsible for a large portion of the total output or results.

Building on Price's Law in the sociology of science, "Matthew effect" was a term coined by Robert K. Merton to describe how, among other things, eminent scientists will often get more credit than a comparatively unknown researcher, even if their work is similar; it also means that credit will usually be given to researchers who are already famous. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_effect The Matthew Effect comes from the Biblical Parable of the Talents wrt how the rich get richer and the poor get poorer. Merton generalized this effect to **all** social institutions and human relationships.

Later, Albert-László Barabási appropriated Price's model without proper attribution or mention of Price, renaming it *preferential attachment*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model

Comment: Let me also submit the [hyperbolastic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolastic_functions) as another collection of s-shaped curves.